# Unpermitted Parameters: profile (NestedAttributes) - RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This question has many times asking by others user but still not solved my problem here. Im having a problem with my rails apps where error "Unpermitted Parameters: profile" appear.

**user_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :store_location, only: [:index]
  before_filter :require_admin

  def edit
    if @user
      render
    else
      redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "User profile not found."
    end
  end

  def update
    # Rails.logger.debug "===> (1)"
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to edit_admin_user_path, notice: "#{@user.profile.full_name} account has been updated."
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:id, :username, :email, profile_attributes: [:user_id, :full_name])
  end
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :user, url: admin_user_path(@user), method: :patch do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :profile, @user.profile do |profile| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= profile.label :full_name %><br>
    <%= profile.text_field : full_name, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile #, update_only: true, allow_destroy: true

  validates :username, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

end
```

**Profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_presence_of :full_name

end
```

**development.log**

```
Started PATCH "/master/users/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-10 23:18:26 +0800
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"23oUfOBaYAmcrfhW3R11F1x53lJAT760Shv0HqkmEzw=", "user"=>{"username"=>"lisa", "profile"=>{"full_name"=>"Evalisa Andriaasdasda"}}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"7"}
[1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
[1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 6  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
Unpermitted parameters: profile
[1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36mUser Exists (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE (`users`.`username` = 'lisa' AND `users`.`id` != 7) LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  COMMIT
[1m[36mProfile Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles`  WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 7 LIMIT 1[0m
```

I really don't know where is the mistake. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Update your `user_params` method to include all of the attributes from the profile object.  You are missing the `id` so rails is trying to create the profile object and this causes undesired behavior (Your development log shows you are making a PATCH request, so you are trying to update something, not create something):

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :username, :email, profile_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :full_name])
end
```

You may also have to update your form to actually pass the `id` of the `profile` object.

See this answer for another look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17561608/1026898

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I solved my own question. For those out there, here is the solution:-

From development.log, i notice something that is `"profile" => {}`. It SHOULD BE `"profile_attributes" => {}` so I modified my `edit.html.erb` form to:-

```
<%= form_for :user, url: admin_user_path(@user), method: :patch do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :profile_attributes, @user.profile do |profile| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= profile.label :full_name %><br>
    <%= profile.text_field :full_name, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Then, I got another error said in development.log:-

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to remove the existing associated profile. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.):
```

So again, I update my `user.rb` to have:-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, update_only: true, allow_destroy: true

  validates :username, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
end
```